# performance.getEntrieByName(); not working on Wordpress Thumbnails images on Firefox

Tags: javascript, wordpress, firefox

I'm creating a WordPress website and want to include a javascript that calculates the size in bytes of pages of the site. I've created this little script that I call with onload on the body.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
    function getPageSize() {
        console.log("tests begin");
        // HTML size 
        var mypagesize;
        var iTimePage = 0;
        iTimePage = performance.getEntriesByName(window.location.href)[0];
        mypagesize = iTimePage.transferSize / 1024.0;

        // images size
        var imgElems = window.document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        console.log(imgElems);
        var myimgsize = 0;
        var iTimeImg = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = imgElems.length; i < len; i++) {
            var url = imgElems[i].src || imgElems[i].href;
            console.log(imgElems);
            if (url && url.length > 0) {
                iTimeImg = performance.getEntriesByName(url)[0];
                console.log(url.length);
                if (iTimeImg) {
                    myimgsize += (iTimeImg.transferSize / 1024.0);
                }
            }
        }
        //CSS size
        var linkElems = window.document.getElementsByTagName('link');
        var mylinksize = 0;
        var iTimeLink = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = linkElems.length; i < len; i++) {
            var url = linkElems[i].src || linkElems[i].href;
            if (url && url.length > 0) {
                iTimeLink = performance.getEntriesByName(url)[0];
                if (iTimeLink) {
                    mylinksize += iTimeLink.transferSize / 1024.0;
                }
            }
        }
        //JS size
        var scriptElems = window.document.getElementsByTagName('script');
        var myscriptsize = 0;
        var iTimeScript = 0;
        for (var i = 0, len = scriptElems.length; i < len; i++) {
            var url = scriptElems[i].src || scriptElems[i].href;
            if (url && url.length > 0) {
                iTimeScript = performance.getEntriesByName(url)[0];
                if (iTimeScript) {
                    myscriptsize += iTimeScript.transferSize / 1024.0;
                }
            }
        }

        var pagesizereduce = Math.round(mypagesize + myimgsize + mylinksize + myscriptsize);
        console.log("tests end");
        console.log(mypagesize);
        console.log(myimgsize);
        console.log(mylinksize);
        console.log(myscriptsize);
        document.getElementById('desktop').innerHTML = pagesizereduce;
        document.getElementById('mobile').innerHTML = pagesizereduce;
    }
</script>
```

The only problem I have is for the images. it works perfectly on Chrome but on Firefox if my image is a featured image on WordPress, the performancegetEntriesByName(); is undefined. If the images are in the post it work perfectly.
Is there a problem with Mozilla handling js differently of chrome ? Or is it a WordPress problem with the featured images on Mozilla ?

Comment: _"the performancegetEntriesByName(); is undefined"_ - `.getEntriesByName()` will always return a list.

Comment: Yeah I know but on Chrome or with image on a post on Firefox, the console.log(iTimeImg); displays : `PerformanceResourceTiming { initiatorType: "img", nextHopProtocol: "h2", workerStart: 0, redirectStart: 0, redirectEnd: 0, fetchStart: 636, domainLookupStart: 636, domainLookupEnd: 636, connectStart: 636, connectEnd: 636 }` but with a featured image it says it is undefined (on Firefox).